# Check the checkboxes under a list onclicking a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have an html code where onclick of parent checkbox all its respective child checkboxes should be checked. Its in the form of a list . Everything works fine but the parent checkbox is clicked and all the child checkboxes following it are also checked.

**myhtml code**

```
<ul class="expandable_ex">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chck" class="parent" onchange="fncheckbox(this);" />      <a onclick="fnUnit()" class="refclass" > 1 princi</a>
        <ul class="expandable">
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="chck" class="child" /> <a onclick="fnUnit()" class="refclass" > 1 lecture </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="chck" class="child" /> <a onclick="fnUnit()"  class="refclass" > 2 lecture </a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="expandable_ex">
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="chck" class="parent" onchange="fncheckbox(this);"/> <a onclick="fnUnit()" class="refclass" > 1 princi</a>
                <ul class="expandable">
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="chck" class="child" /> <a onclick="fnUnit()" class="refclass" > 1 lecture </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="chck" class="child" /> <a onclick="fnUnit()"  class="refclass" > 2 lecture </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**my js code**

```
function fncheckbox(checkBox){
    if($(checkBox).is(':checked')){
        $(checkBox).closest('li').find('.child').attr("checked",true);
    }
}
```

[Updated Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5N6TL/15/)

Here is my fiddle where when i click on "1 princi" checkbox the children under it is checked as well as the children of the second "1 princi " is also checked. I want only the checkboxes of respective children should be checked. How to fix this?

Comment: Seems to work fine if you pick the right option to load your JS. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5N6TL/14/

Comment: Sorry  actual fiddle is this http://jsfiddle.net/5N6TL/15/

Comment: Are you saying only the direct children should be selected?

Comment: yes only the direct children to be selected

Comment: What about if you uncheck it? Should the children become unchecked? And what about if you check the parent and then uncheck a child? Should the parent become unchecked? Or indeterminate?

Comment: If i uncheck it the children should be unchecked. If i uncheck a child parent need not be unchecked it can remain checked.

Comment: FYI IDs **must** be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `siblings()` instead of `closest()` , updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5N6TL/17/)

```
$(checkBox).siblings('.expandable').find('.child').attr("checked",true);
```

Comment: Thanks Vidya. Happy Learning

Answer (score 1):

See the fiddle below :
http://jsfiddle.net/Maryyy/eLE7g/

One solution is to add a specific class to parents and childs, and select child with the same class as the parent.

```
function fncheckbox(checkBox){  
     if($(checkBox).is(':checked')){  
         var classParent = "." + $(checkBox).attr('class');  
         $(classParent).attr("checked",true);  
     }  
}
```

Comment: @Mary : Your fiddle is not available. I request you to post the fiddle again.

Comment: Oops, it's now available, I change the URL, sorry!